# How Register in prestashop only through email id and password

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I am new to prestashop thats why i am facing problem in making it possible to register only through email and password. How to register in prestashop only through email id and password. What changes should be done in php file to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

From prestashop >=1.5.

Override Customer class like that:

```
Class Customer extends CustomerCore {
    public function __construct($id = null){
        self::$definition['fields']['lastname'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => false, 'size' => 32);
        self::$definition['fields']['firstname'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => false, 'size' => 32);
        parent::__construct($id);
    }
}
```

Change in your DB the field 'firstname', 'lastname' with two query like these ( note that 'ps_' is the default table prefix ):

```
ALTER TABLE `ps_customer` CHANGE  `firstname`  `firstname` VARCHAR( 32 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL;
ALTER TABLE `ps_customer` CHANGE  `lastname`  `lastname` VARCHAR( 32 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL
```

This is the procedure that allow to user to subscribe without inserting first name and last name.

Pay very attention, that is a core edit, and something can not working anymore. You are distorting the ideologic functionality of PrestaShop.